# POST api Rest with AT Commands - SIM800

Tags: http, post, gsm, at-command

I'm having problems sending post parameters over a SIM800 module using AT. For while I'm using FTDI and mac screen application terminal.

Here is my command sequence:

```
AT+HTTPINIT
AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","myhost/deviceRegister"
AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"
AT+HTTPDATA=94,120000
OK

DOWNLOAD
POST deviceRegister HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost
Content-Length:13

{"IMEI":"aa"}
AT+HTTPACTION=1
AT+HTTPREAD
```

Until here, everything looks fine, but when I log my post request in my server what I have is this:

```
+HTTPREAD: 259
POST deviceRegister HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost
Accept: */*
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: SIMCOM_MODULE
Content-Length: 94


{"IMEI":"aa"}gister HTTP/1.1

OK
```

It looks like it is posting to the body without \n

Why my post body has headers parameters ?

Answer (score 1):

That s what i tried on my sim900 modem
{"myvar1="myvalue1","myvar2"="myvalue2"} is my json object

```
AT+CGATT?

AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"

AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","mynetworkprovider.com"

AT+SAPBR=3,1,"USER","mylogin"

AT+SAPBR=3,1,"PWD","mypassword"

AT+SAPBR=1,1

AT+HTTPINIT

AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1

AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://myserveraddress/comm.php"

AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"

AT+HTTPDATA=137,5000 **=>SIM response : DOWNLOAD**

Content-Length: 414

{"myvar1="myvalue1","myvar2"="myvalue2"}


AT+HTTPACTION=1

AT+HTTPREAD =>should respond 200 http ok status
```

hth

Answer (score 0):

I m not an expert but on my sim900 modem i tried this and it works for me

AT commands to initialize Modem for data transfert
and

```
AT+HTTPINIT

AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1

AT+HTTPPARA="URL","myhost/deviceRegister"

AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"

AT+HTTPDATA=94,120000

OK

DOWNLOAD

Content-Length:13

{"IMEI":"aa"}

AT+HTTPACTION=1

AT+HTTPREAD
```

Hope this help